# Is a model a client of her agency or a worker?

Tags: word-choice, identifier-choice

I want to write the following sentence:

Paul Saint knew that he was going to have to fight this through with the fresh face model that all the top designers his agency dealt with were clamouring for. Kenny was going to be a tough client.

My question, if Paul Saint runs a modelling agency where Kenny is being pitched to the designers and advertisers, does she work for him or him for her? And in that scenario, is she a client? Or what other designation is more suitable to describe her?

Comment: This seems to be a legal question.

Comment: No, Michael.hor257k. I'm not looking at the legal implication of the relationship but a word that's usually used for a model within the industry. I want to know if she is called a client of the agency or if there's another word for her.

Comment: No, Michael.hor257k. I'm not looking at the legal implication of the relationship but a word that's usually used for a model within the industry. I want to know if she is called a client of the agency or if there's another word for her.

Comment: The word that is used will depend on the legal relationship. Most agencies take a fee for connecting (in this case) models with customers wanting to hire them; but there are, in every industry, agencies that employ staff who are hired out to customers for  short periods.

Comment: She is an *asset* of the agency!

Comment: Note that "worker" will likely be avoided, as it hints of "sex worker".

Comment: @HotLicks Although the term *talent* is used by the industry, despite similar connotations. See subhead [here](https://www.modelsdirect.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 'worker' is appropriate at all, and neither is 'client'. The agency's *clients* are the designers who are clamouring for her, and the agency's *workers* are the people who keep her shoes clean. I think Mahmud has a point with his suggestion of 'asset'. In a way, she is the commodity that they are selling to the client.

Illogically, *customer* might be your best bet, because the phrase *a tough customer* exists in its own right as "a difficult person to deal with", regardless of whether they're a customer or not.

By the way, you should say *fresh-faced*, and the sentence construction with "clamouring for" at the end is awkward. And Kenny is a man's name, so you might want to reconsider that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing, but the short answer is yes. The useage of *client* depends on perspective, and there is nothing wrong with using it to describe the talent's relationship with the booking agent.

> A talent agent, or booking agent, is a person who finds jobs for actors, authors, film directors, musicians, models, professional athletes, writers, screenwriters, broadcast journalists, and other people in various entertainment or broadcast businesses. In addition, an agent defends, supports and promotes the interest of their **clients**.

"talent agent" wikipedia

The issue here is the term *agent*, and the legal idea of agency. The talent agent may be an agent for the model, an agent for those seeking talent, or both. Dual agent status normally has to be revealed to both parties, as conflict of interest is a real concern.